# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+x+1}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals

As in the title I was evaluating the integral,

$$I:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+x+1}\,dx$$

But numerically speaking, I seemed to have gotten an incorrect answer. What have I done wrong? Here is my work.

Let

$$x\longrightarrow{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$

$$I=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan(x)}{3+x^2}\,dx$$

$I.B.P$

$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

Let

$$x\longrightarrow{\tan(x)}$$

$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}J$$

$$J:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\,dx$$

To evaluate $J$ define:

$$J(t):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\left(t\tan(x)\right)\,dx$$

We can see that:

$$J(0)=0,J\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=J$$

Now it follows that from the $F.T.C.$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}J’(t)\,dt$$

And so:

$$J’(t)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan(x)}{t^2\tan^2(x)+1}\,dx$$

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sec(x)$ then let:

$$\sec(x)\longrightarrow{x}$$

$$J’(t)=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{x(t^2x^2+1-t^2)}\,dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{1-t^2}\left[\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx-\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{t^2x}{t^2x^2+1-t^2}\,dx\right]$$

$$J’(t)=\frac{1}{1-t^2}\frac{1}{2}\left[\log(2)-\log(1+t^2)\right]$$

And so

$$J=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{1}{1-t^2}\left[\log(2)-\log(1+t^2)\right]\,dt$$

Let

$$t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$

$$J=\frac{1}{4}\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\log\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\left[2\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx-\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\log(x+i)}{x}\,dx-\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\log(x-i)}{x}\,dx\right]$$

Now using

$$\int\frac{\log(x+a)}{x}\,dx=\log(a)\log(x)-Li_{2}\left(-\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4}\left[2Li_{2}(-x)+Li_{2}(ix)+Li_{2}(-ix)\right]_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}$$

Using:

$$Li_{2}(z)+Li_{2}(-z)=\frac{1}{2}Li_{2}(z^2)$$

We have

$$=-\frac{1}{4}\left[2Li_{2}(-x)+\frac{1}{2}Li_{2}(-x^2)\right]_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}$$

And so

$$J=\frac{5\pi^2}{96}+\frac{1}{4}\left[2Li_{2}(\sqrt{3}-2)+\frac{1}{2}Li_{2}(4\sqrt{3}-7)\right]$$

And so we have that

$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{7\pi^2}{96\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}\left[2Li_{2}(\sqrt{3}-3)+\frac{1}{2}Li_{2}(4\sqrt{3}-7)\right]$$

Where did I how wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No need complex numbers, you get this integral $\displaystyle \int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx$ from this one $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\log\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$, a simple change of variable $u=x^2$ in the first integral leads to an integral that is easy to express in terms of dilogaritms.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
I &:= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{x^{2}+x+1}dx \\
&\overset{x \mapsto \frac{1-x}{1+x}}= 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan x}{3+x^{2}}dx \\
&\overset{IBP}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan\left(x\right)\right)\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{1+x^{2}}dx \\
&= \color{red}{0}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{1+x^{2}}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}\left(\ln2-\ln\left(1+t^{2}\right)\right)dt\, \small\text{ (assuming you did the Leibniz integral rule right)} \\
&\overset{t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{x}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(2\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)}{x}dx-\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(\left(x+i\right)\left(x-i\right)\right)}{x}dx\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(2\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)}{x}dx-\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(x+i\right)}{x}dx-\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(x-i\right)}{x}dx\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left[-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(-x\right)-\left(\ln\left(i\right)\ln\left(x\right)-\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(-\frac{x}{i}\right)\right)-\left(\ln\left(-i\right)\ln\left(x\right)-\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{x}{i}\right)\right)\right]_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1} \\
&= \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left[2\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(-x\right)\color{red}{-}\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(-x^{2}\right)\right]_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1} \\
&= \frac{\pi^{2}}{16\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(4\sqrt{3}-7\right)}{4\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: N.B. Maybe it's worth mentioning that $\ln((x+i)(x-i)) \neq \ln(x+i) + \ln(x-i)$ in general due to branch cut issues, but we can use a branch like the principal branch for these three logs and see that $\arg(x+i) + \arg(x-i) = 0$ for all $x \in (2-\sqrt{3},1)$ to eventually justify splitting the logarithm nicely.